# Saving Nested Domain Objects in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

**I UPDATE THE ISSUE BELOW**

I am trying to save a series of nested Domain Objects in Grails and I running into issues with the syntax for this.

As an example, lets say I have the following nested one-to-many relationships:

Artist->Album->Song

I first create an Artist

```
Artist artist = new Artist(parameters)
artist.save()
```

With the newly saved Artist I wish to then save a series of Albums and their associated Songs.

I thought something like this would work but I am getting mixed results.

```
Album album = new Album()
artist.addToAlbum(album)
Song song = new Song()
album.addToSong(song)
```

What I see is a new Album domain object, but no new Song.  I tried a simple println to check the status of the "album" and it returns a null.  So clearly I can add an Album to the existing Artist, but I am not getting back the Album itself so that I can add Songs.  Can someone shed some light on how to save multiple nested objects in GORM/Grails?

Thank you

Actual Domains: Nested DataLoad->DataSeries->ReportedResult

DataLoad

```
class DataLoad {

static hasMany = [dataSeries: DataSeries]
String fileLocation
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
CROSource croSource

List dataSeries = new ArrayList()

static mapping = {

     dataSeries cascade:"all-delete-orphan"

}}
```

DataSeries

```
class DataSeries {

//parent and child relationships one-to-many
static belongsTo = [dataLoad: DataLoad]
static hasMany = [reportedResult: ReportedResult]
//this functions as an experiment_id for data which needs to be viewed together
String randomString
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated

List reportedResult = new ArrayList()
static mapping = {
     reportedResult cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
}}
```

ReportedResult

```
class ReportedResult implements Serializable {


//parent and child relationships one-to-many
static belongsTo = [dataSeries: DataSeries]
static hasMany = [resultDefData: ResultDefData]
List resultDefData = new ArrayList()
//has one-to-one relationship   -may need to make this a one sided relationship does not always need a Curve
Curve curve

AssayGroup assayGroup
AssayDefinition assayDefinition
AssayProtocol assayProtocol
ResultStatistic resultStatistic
ResultType resultType

//actual result fields
Float resultValue
String resultValueUnit
String resultModifier
Boolean resultObtained
Date resultTime
Integer compoundID
Float resultStatValue
String resultComment
Float resultRawValue

String linkToExternalFile
String studyNumber


Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated


static mapping = {
resultDefData cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
}}
```

**UPDATE**

So if I try something like the following, it works.  Must be something else in one of my domains. I will try to fix my issue, but for reference this should work.

```
Artist artist = new Artist(artistName: "MyName")
artist.save()

    Album album = new Album(albumName: "myAlbum")
    artist.addToAlbums(album)

  Song song = new Song(songName: "just a song")
    album.addToSongs(song)
```

Comment: What are the names of the `hasMany` fields in the parent objects? If they are plural (`static hasMany = ['songs': Song]`) then your `addTo` needs to be plural as well: `album.addToSongs(song)`

Comment: Kelly- thanks for the response.  So you are correct that I am in fact adding more like the following `artist.addToAlbums(albums: album)` this does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you post your domains ?

Comment: Sure, I added the real domains I am working with.  I was using Artist/Album/Song to try to make things more readable

Comment: Try to validate your instances before of the addTo*

Comment: Sergio - I think you are correct in that the instances need validation.  I think there is something wrong with ReportedResult class.  Thank you

Comment: @Dennis, 1) if you aren't already doing this, issue a save() on 'Artist' after you're done adding albums and songs. 2) When you save(), try a println artist.errors and see what validation errors come up.

Comment: When I run into that kind of validation issue, i add failOnError to save: save(failOnError:true, flush:true)  to make sure that save will not fail silently. This will cause validation errors to throw an exception.

Comment: Loteq- Thanks for the advice, that is helpful I did not know about the failOnError option.  Also uchamp thank you!  I am going to edit the post to update my current code so hopefully future folks have an example...Again thanks to ALL